# Why is ActiveRecord only looking for a model object with an id = 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to destroy links that belong to a category model (through my browser). I can successfully delete a link that has an `id` of `1` and `category_id` of `1`, but when I try to delete a link that has any other id I get hit with:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LinksController#destroy
Couldn't find Link with id=1 [WHERE "links"."category_id" = 1]
```

Very frustrating, because I'm not trying to delete a link that has an id of 1! But I see in the request parameters that it's always trying to delete a link with `"category_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"1"}`, no matter what link I click on. Looking at the links in my development database confirms they exist and have ids that are not 1...

Here's the code for LinksController#destroy:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @link = @category.links.find(params[:id])
    @link.destroy
    redirect_to category_url(@category)
end
```

Here's the code for the view where I'm trying to delete these pesky links:

```
<h1><%= @category.category %></h1>
<p><%=  @category.description %></p> 
<ul>
    <% @category.links.each do |link| %>
    <li>
    <%= link_to link.title, link.url %> |
    <%= link_to "delete", category_link_path(@category), :method => :delete %>
    </li>
 <% end %>
```

Edit: Added parameters

```
{"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"[removed]",
 "category_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

Edit: Added config/routes.rb:

```
LinkManager::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :categories do
    resources :links, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end

  root :to => 'categories#index'
```

What am I overlooking? Is there anything I can try?

Comment: Really weird: `@category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @link = @category.links.find(params[:id])`

Comment: You use the same `params[:id]` to find both a `Category` object AND a `Link`, that will not work for sure! Can you add the output of `params.inspect` when you try to destroy the link please?

Comment: I'm new to Rails, would you please explain why that wouldn't work? Will edit and add the parameters.

Comment: Hmm can you try with `link_path(link)` instead of `category_link_path(@category)` and show me the params?

Comment: @MrYoshiji, changing the URI to link_path(link) gives me a NoMethodError exception, I think because my links resource is nested under the categories resource in routes.rb? Doesn't that change the _path links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `category_link_path` is ommitting something. Perhaps it should look like this?

```
<%= link_to "delete", category_link_path(@category, link), :method => :delete %>
```

It looks like you're fulfilling the `category_id` part of the route by passing in `@category`, but you also need to provide `link` as the `id`.

Then you need to fix your `destroy` action as such:

```
def destroy
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  @link = @category.links.find(params[:id])
  @link.destroy
  redirect_to category_url(@category)
end
```

Comment: Hmm... I made the changes, and now I can't view the page at all and just see: `Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"links", :category_id=>#<Category id: 1, category: "categoryname", description: "blahblah", created_at: "2012-11-14 14:01:14", updated_at: "2012-11-14 14:01:14">, :id=>#<Link id: nil, title: nil, url: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, category_id: 1>}`

Comment: I believe the helper should be called `categories_link_path`, not `category_link_path`. Try that. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Apologies. Was incorrect on the helper path name. Sorry, got my wires crossed.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately now I'm seeing this: `undefined method 'categories_link_path' for #<#<Class:0x441a368>:0x441fe28>`. Oh well!

Comment: If you look at the error message, you'll see that `link` is `nil` for some reason. Any ideas why?

Comment: Just to be clear, the helper name should be `category_link_path`. I gave you bunk advice. Sorry about that. Also, you'll see from the routing error in your first comment that `link.id` is `nil` for some reason. Any ideas why?

Comment: I think it may be the deleted link with the id of 1 I was referencing in my post? Rails keeps trying to pull that record from the database even though it doesn't exist. I must've royally screwed up somewhere!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19537/discussion-between-chris-peters-and-hlh)

Answer (score 1):

On your category_link_path you should be passing your category as well as your link. something like

`category_link_path(@category, link)`

Also, on your controller, to find your category it should look like `Category.find(params[:category_id]`